# Web server does not restart after ssl_engine is set

Tags: nginx, ssl, amazon-web-services

I am trying to offload SSL process to AWS CloudHSM. While configuring the web server, when I add this:

```
ssl_engine cloudhsm;
```

to the top of the nginx configuration, nginx does not get restarted and the following error was logged:

```
2018/05/29 11:53:58 [emerg] 17509#0: ENGINE_by_id("cloudhsm") failed (SSL: error:25066067:DSO support routines:dlfcn_load:could not load the shared library:filename(/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/engines-1.1/cloudhsm.so): /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/engines-1.1/cloudhsm.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory error:25070067:DSO support routines:DSO_load:could not load the shared library error:260B6084:engine routines:dynamic_load:dso not found error:2606A074:engine routines:ENGINE_by_id:no such engine:id=cloudhsm)
```

How do I resolve this?

Comment: You apparently don't have the AWS CloudHSM client and command line tools installed.

Comment: I have activated my cluster and imported the keys to the module and also exported the fake pem key for the private key too. Is there anything else that would cause this error?

Comment: You are missing at least the shared library that implements cloudhsm for nginx, hence my comment that you don't have all the necessary things installed. You have really only configured things, something also needs to be installed. I'm sure AWS can help you with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I experienced the same issue, and documented by findings and solution in this [Github issue](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-cloudhsm-user-guide/issues/17).

In summary, if you have followed the steps in:

- [Install and Use the AWS CloudHSM Dynamic Engine for OpenSSL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudhsm/latest/userguide/openssl-library-install.html#install-openssl-library)
- SSL/TLS Offload on Linux -> [Step 3: Configure the Web Server](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudhsm/latest/userguide/ssl-offload-configure-web-server.html)

then you have CloudHSM configured correctly, and you can access it with your regular user, but the user that launches `nginx` cannot (which results in the misleading error that you report). See the solution post above for simple tests that you can run to verify that is indeed the case.

The solution is to track down how the server is started (see [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/164092/297701) to find out what init system your system uses), and make sure that the cloudhsm credentials are part of that environment. The instructions from AWS assume that the host runs `systemd` as the init system. In my case, I was using `init` and the solution involved tracking down the corresponding script and passing the credentials (`n3fips_password`) before launching `nginx`. Again the specific details are documented in the [Github thread](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-cloudhsm-user-guide/issues/17).